# Query to get 10 track with full info from other table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 table
song table

[image]

album table

[image]

Artist table
[image]

I want to get 10 latest song from table song with full info included album name, album ID, album cover, artist name (multi artist in some case), artist ID,... for each song. I use this query but it's not work

```
SELECT song.SID, artist.NAME, song.COVER, song.TITLE, album.COVER AS ACOVER, album.TITLE AS ATITLE, album.AID 
FROM song
INNER JOIN album ON album.SONG LIKE CONCAT('%,',song.ID,',%') 
INNER JOIN artist ON song.ARTIST LIKE CONCAT('%,',artist.ID,',%') 
ORDER BY song.ID DESC
```

Something wrong here?

Comment: I see you are storing lots of comma separated lists in your tables.  _Don't_ do that please.  Instead, give each album-song combination its own separate record, for example.  If you continue with your current design, it will only be a bigger headache later on, even if someone gives you an answer here.

Comment: Can you give me some idea to save album list song and artist list, please. I have a thousand of album

Comment: I did give you some idea.  Normalize your data, and just have one relationship per record.

Comment: Each song should be listed as it's own row in a table, with a relationship to the album, probably a column called `album_id`, then each album simply has an id. This way, you can associate each song row with an album row without storing comma separated lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tim Biegeleisen mentioned, I would recommend you too to normalize your data before going ahead.

I would create two new relantionship tables:

```
AlbumxSong with fields:
AID
SID

ArtistxSong with fields:
SIID
SID
```

Then you would not need the `ARTIST` field in the `Song` table. The same with `SONG` field in `Album` table. You would have that info in the relationship tables.

I hope that helps.